# Know which process does I/O without iotop

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, io, proc

On Linux, I want to know which process uses my disk I/O bandwith.

I know I can use `iotop` but I have a machine where, for various reasons, `iotop` cannot be installed.

How can I manually get that information? (How does `iotop` itself proceed?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The file in `/proc/<pid>/io` represent what you need. It's a bit scripting work to get an output similar to `iotop`. See the [linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) to the `/proc/<pid>/io` file values:

> **rchar**
>
> I/O counter: chars read The number of bytes which this task has caused
>   to be read from storage. This is simply the sum of bytes which this
>   process passed to read() and pread(). It includes things like tty IO
>   and it is unaffected by whether or not actual physical disk IO was
>   required (the read might have been satisfied from pagecache)
>
> **wchar**
>
> I/O counter: chars written The number of bytes which this task has
>   caused, or shall cause to be written to disk. Similar caveats apply
>   here as with rchar.
>
> [...]
>
> **read_bytes**
>
> I/O counter: bytes read Attempt to count the number of bytes which
>   this process really did cause to be fetched from the storage layer.
>   Done at the submit_bio() level, so it is accurate for block-backed
>   filesystems.
>
> **write_bytes**
>
> I/O counter: bytes written Attempt to count the number of bytes which
>   this process caused to be sent to the storage layer. This is done at
>   page-dirtying time.

Now, you can use that small `bash` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo "Must be root" 2>&1
  exit 1
fi

delay=2
lista=$(for p in $(pgrep "."); do echo -n "$p "; grep ^rchar /proc/$p/io 2>/dev/null; done)

while :; do

  echo "-----"
  listb=$(for p in $(pgrep "."); do echo -n "$p "; grep ^rchar /proc/$p/io 2>/dev/null; done)

  echo "$lista" | while read -r pida xa bytesa; do
    [ -e "/proc/$pida" ] || continue
    echo -en "$pida:\t"
    bytesb=$(echo "$listb" | awk -v pid=$pida '$1==pid{print $3}')
    echo "$((($bytesb - $bytesa) / $delay)) b/s"
  done | sort -nk2 | tail
  sleep $delay
  listb=$lista
done
```

It creates two lists with a delay of 2 seconds (`$delay`: can be in- or decreased) between them, and then compares the lists and calculates the differences. The 10 process with the most I/O are printed with their I/O bandwith in the last 2 seconds. If you want write I/O instead of read I/O just edit the `grep` command in the lists to `wchar` instead of `rchar`:

```bash
lista=$(for p in $(pgrep "."); do echo -n "$p "; grep ^wchar /proc/$p/io 2>/dev/null; done)
listb=$(for p in $(pgrep "."); do echo -n "$p "; grep ^wchar /proc/$p/io 2>/dev/null; done)
```